# How can I include multiple html files in my initial page load using Node?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

By this I mean I want my index.html file to load two other files ...

In PHP you would just add two includes to the index.html as such

```
...
<?php include file1.htm>
<?php include file2.htm>
...
```

Node works as such

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
})
```

But how can I have that index.html file include two other files?

Comment: Use `<iframe>`s.

Comment: how so? ... that is an html construct